# Agregar decimales o comas a input según spinner

Tags: jquery, spinner

Hola amigos necesito ayuda tengo esta funcionalidad tengo un valor o monto por defecto en un `input` `hidden` el cual esta multiplicando con el valor del `input` `quantity`, este resultado se muestra en el `input` total, hasta allí bien este se va sumando cuando con el `sipiner` vas incrementado y lo multiplica por el valor por default, lo que necesito es que el campo total, a partir de 1000, le agregue comas, separadores, `1,000.00` algo así.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quantity').spinner({
        min: 0,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var qty = this.value;
            var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
            var total = qty * price;
            $('#total').val(total);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="valor-defecto">
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="5000">
</div>

<div class="spinner">
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity" id="quantity">
</div>

<div class="total">
<input class="total" type="text" name="total" id="total" required value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: si el ejemplo no corre bien , como podemos ayudarte?, puedes agregar la libreria al snippet?

Comment: ya esta cooregido, por favor su ayuda gracias

Comment: quieres que el input tenga formato numerico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podría utilizar [NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat) para  dar el formato adecuado , pero dicho formato retornará en `$` si desea lo deja tal y como está, si desea remover solo usaría un `replace()` *como en el ejemplo.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quantity').spinner({
        min: 0,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var qty = this.value;
            var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
            var total = qty * price;
            $('#total').val(formatter.format(total).replace('$',''));
        }
    });
    var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
   style: 'currency',
   currency: 'USD'
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="valor-defecto">
<input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="price" id="price" value="5000">
</div>

<div class="spinner">
<input type="text" value="0" name="quantity" id="quantity">
</div>

<div class="total">
<input class="total" type="text" name="total" id="total" required value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio era lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta función que retorna el valor con separación por coma.
O puedes utilizar el metodo toLocaleString();

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toLocaleString

```js
const numberWithCommas = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


document.write(numberWithCommas(1000));

 var number = 3500;

 document.write('<br>', number.toLocaleString());
```